# Guardar lista de objetos del lado del cliente

Tags: c#, asp.net

Como dice el titulo, necesitaría guardar una lista de un determinado objeto del lado del cliente (en este caso seria una lista de localidades).

Lo que tengo es un TextBox que en el evento de `TextChanged`, obtiene una lista de localidades por el código postal que tiene este TXT. Esto hace que se rellene un Drop Down List con todas las localidades con ese Bodigo postal.

Lo que quisiera es que esa lista se guarde del lado del cliente porque luego dependiendo del item que se elija en el dropdownlist rellena un textbox con el nombre de la provincia, pero para esto primero necesita saber que localidad es la que eligió.

También ¿como podría hacer que se ejecute un evento cuando el Drop Down List pierda foco?

Comment: no estoy seguro, pero podrias usar la cache del usuario.

Comment: Te recomiendo dividir tu pregunta en apartados ya que te ha quedado un párrafo muy grande. Adjunta las ideas que se te hayan ocurrido o el código que has intentado , así , facilitaras el trabajo a los usuarios que te quieran ayudar. Un saludo :)

Comment: No sería mejor traer todas las localidades junto con las provincias de una vez, y después simplemente filtrar mediante JQuery lo que necesites.. asi evitas consultar a la API N veces

Comment: Claro @PauloUrbanoRivera eso es lo que pensaba, pero no se bien como hacerlo. Porque lo que haria yo seria asi. Por ajax pediria todas las localidades con determinado codigo postal (que ya tienen la provincia dentro de sus propiedades), pero no sabria como almacenarlas y se filtre dependiendo del id de localidad que se seleccione en el drop down list.

Comment: Manejando el evento de onchange puedes tener acceso a las variables y filtrar según el id con una función find por ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

No se si el problema que tienes es mas extenso pero podrías utilizar el localstorage del usuario para ello, así podrías consultar el objeto en vez de consultar el api en reiteradas ocasiones:

Ejem Javascript:

let objeto = {valorA: "hola, valorB: "Mundo"}

window.localStorage.setItem("nombre", objeto)

//obtener valor

let objetoAlmacenado = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("nombre"))

console.log(objetoAlmacenado .valorA) //hola

Comment: Me gusta la idea, voy a probar a ver si puedo hacerlo funcionar con lo mio.